# Classification tree from a binomial glmnet model?

Tags: r, tree, classification, rpart, glmnet

I very much like the simplicity of classification trees for presentations and posters, as they are more aligned with the clinical decision making and therefore provides a familiar way for the reader to digest the fit of a binomial model. However, in the work I am currently doing, I have had to use binomial response `glmnet` models, as my main aim is to reduce the set of possible predictors to the smaller set of actually productive ones.

I have a couple of models that are well balances and reasonably accurate, with 6-12 non-zero predictors in them. Is there any way to transform the models to a visual classification tree somehow, similar to what you can get from an `rpart` model and the rpart.plot package?

I can of course use `rpart` instead, but I loose predictive power then, as fewer predictors are identified.

Comment: They aren't really the same are they? `rpart` is a series of branching predictors and `glmnet` is a (sort of) addition of predictors. So such a plot would be misleading? No?

Comment: That said... and come to think of it... the lasso plots show the predictor importance... but shouldn't be confused with `rpart` like plots https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154825/what-to-conclude-from-this-lasso-plot-glmnet